Sequelize on NodeJS/ExpressJS return an error when running CLI command db:create
npx sequelize db:create
i was trying to do create "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2" version
but i got
also this is error
mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
"development": {
"username": "root",
"password": "",
"database": "Flights_Search_DB_DEV",
"host": "127.0.0.1",
"dialect": "mysql"
},
expecting to create db with sequelize cli

Check if you're running mysql, maybe it's turned off
Try running mysql in terminal or if you're on Windows find mysql service and see if its running.
Username and password should also be correct to successfully connect to the database
If you forgot your password (happened to me a few times) then see below
You should create init txt file with sql command (in the link) then start mysql with this file, instructions here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-reset-your-mysql-or-mariadb-root-password

with mysql server it was not working i was trying with that but with this is  sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
it is working

I suggest you to create a user for your mysql and then run mysql with mysql -u user -p example-password
